# Find all occurrences of string after another string in all files

Tags: grep

My end goal is to have a script that will count the instances of each username in all files.

A username is a string, in quotes, that follows the string 'login'. For example, in one file, I might have:

```
{"this":"is', {"a":"strange"}, "type":{"of":"object", "but":"please"},
 "go":"withit", "login":"username1"}

{"this":"is', {"login":"username2"}, "type":{"of":"object", "but":"please"},
 "go":"withit"}
```

And in another file, I  might have:

```
{"this":"is', {"a":"strange"}, "type":{"of":"object", "but":"please"},
 "go":"withit", "login":"username3"}

{"login":"username1", "please":"gowithit"}
```

In which case, I'd like to have a txt file that contains a dict object with the count of the number of times each username appears in the files:

```
{"username1": 2, "username2":1, "username3":1}
```

I've read a few [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep) to [get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193251/regex-to-get-the-words-after-matching-string) me [started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/how-to-grep-for-contents-after-pattern), but I can't seem to put this together. I've sort of pseudocoded it, but I can't progress from this point.

I think I need to do this in two stages.

1) Get a list of all the usernames

2) Count the number of times each username appears in all files.

For task 1):

```
 grep 'login:' * | sed 's/^.*: //'
#Except I think this gets everything from the line after 'login', which isn't what I want.
```

For task 2):

```
for all_usernames_in_file:
     stringval = username_read_from_saved_file
     cat * | grep -c $stringval > output.txt
```

Can anyone take it from here?

EDIT:

Do you mean I should do this:

```
grep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' /path/to/dir/* | cut -d'"' -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sed '1i{ s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)/"\2": \1,/;$a}' > output.txt
```

EDIT 2: Still not working. I'm trying to diagnose by understanding what each command does.

Let's say I'm just looking at this part to start:

```
grep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' /path/to/dir/* | cut -d'"' -f3 | sort | uniq -c > myfile.txt
```

Right now, `myfile.txt` is blank.

Here's what I think this command is doing:

`grep -o` matches non-empty parts of a matching line.

`'login":"[^"]*"'` is the string we want grep to match. In the middle, the `[^"]` matches any character after `login":"` not equal to `"`, and the `*` says we want any length of match - that is, the length of the username doesn't matter, we want everything between the quotes.

`|` is a pipe. It means "and then"

`cut -d '"' -f3` means slice up the returned line (all stuff after `login":"`), using the delimiter `"`, and take field 3 (that is, just the username).

`|` is a pipe. It means "and then"

`sort` the usernames

`|` is a pipe. It means "and then"

Get the unique usernames and count the number of times each appears.

If I take that much, and put a `> myfile.txt` at the end, then I should end up with a txt file that contains usernames and a count of the number of times each appears. It won't be well-formatted, but it will exist.

Why am I not getting such a file?

NOTE: does it matter that I'm searching through `.json.gz` formatted files? I've gotten the script to work when searching through `txt`, but not through the other format.

Comment: Are the documents in fact JSON? Is the single quote in `{"this":"is',` a typo?

Comment: If this is supposed to be JSON documents, could you please add properly formatted examples of these documents? At the moment, the data is _not_ JSON and any attempt to parse them using a proper JSON parser (`jq`) fails due to stray objects without keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you always have login and value in double quotes following each other without spaces here's a construction to grep and count it:

```
grep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' * | cut -d'"' -f3 | sort | uniq -c
```

This will produce list of logins with a number of occurrences.

Now we need to form from it a json format you need. `sed` is able to do that for you:

```
| sed '1i{
       s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)/"\2": \1,/;$a}'
```

Here `sed` will put `{` in the beginning of block and `}` to its end, and change `uniq` output to json format you expect.

UPD: In the end final command should look this way:

```
grep -o 'login":"[^"]*"' * | cut -d'"' -f3 | sort | uniq -c | sed '1i{
       s/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\(.*\)/"\2": \1,/;$a}' > file.txt
```

Comment: Does this result in a txt file that contains all usernames and their frequencies?

Comment: Yeah, if you concatenate all the commands and redirect the output to the file, it should.

Comment: Silly question: do you put these two commands together on the same line? Please see the edit?

Comment: @StatsSorceress I've added it to the answer. Please note that linebreak in `sed` is a very important. Otherwise it will insert in the beginning of block entire sed command instead.

Comment: That didn't work. It gave me a file containing {
"[^": 1,
}

Comment: Please see the new edit? It's still not working

Comment: Fixed by using zgrep

Answer (score 1):

To get all usernames, i.e. all string associated with a `login` key, from a *well formed JSON document*, without knowing the document structure:

```
jq -r '..|select(.login?).login' file.json
```

Applying this to a number of JSON files, and sorting and counting the result:

```
jq -r '..|select(.login?).login' *.json | sort | uniq -c
```

The `jq` expression used here is

- `..`: Recurse through all keys and values.
- `select(.login?)`: Select the encountered objects that contain a `login` key.
- `.login`: Get the value for that key.

The dictionary thing you'd like to have, building on the above `jq` expression:

```
jq -sr '[..|select(.login?).login]|group_by(.)|map({key:.[0],value:length})|from_entries' *.json
```

Testing:

```
$ cat file.json
{"this":"is", "A":{"login":"username2"}, "type":{"of":"object", "but":"please"},
 "go":"withit", "login":"me"}
```

```
$ jq -sr '[..|select(.login?).login]|group_by(.)|map({key:.[0],value:length})|from_entries' file.json
{
  "me": 1,
  "username2": 1
}
```

Giving it the same file twice:

```
$ jq -sr '[..|select(.login?).login]|group_by(.)|map({key:.[0],value:length})|from_entries' file.json f
ile.json
{
  "me": 2,
  "username2": 2
}
```

Use `jq` with `-c` to get the single line compact output.

For our example file, `jq -sr '[..|select(.login?).login]' file.json` would produce

```
[
  "me",
  "username2"
]
```

Passing this through `group_by(.)` gives

```
[
  [
    "me"
  ],
  [
    "username2"
  ]
]
```

The `map({key:.[0],value:length})` part gives

```
[
  {
    "key": "me",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "key": "username2",
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

and the `from_entries` at the end gives the final result.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a perl hash keyed on a regex match, which you can convert using the JSON module:

```
$ perl -MJSON -lne '$h{$1}++ for /(?<="login":")(.*?)(?=")/g }{ print encode_json \%h' file1 file2
{"username3":1,"username2":1,"username1":2}
```

Comment: Took me a few minutes to get my head around this but its sweet. Why do you need the 'l' switch?

Comment: @bu5hman TBH I'm hazy on the perl `-l` switch (autochomp?) - I tend to just throw it in if the newline handling screws up (forgive me, perl gods). There's a discussion of what it does here: [The top 10 tricks of Perl one-liners](https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/the-top-10-tricks-of-perl-one-liners-v2)

Comment: Fair enough. Can you also educate a perl script kiddie like me as to why the print only executes once under the '-n' switch? Is this a perl specific construct?

Comment: @bu5hman not sure where it's documented, but the `}{` is a cheat way of making everything to the right into an `END{ }` block; everything to the left is looped over per the `-n` switch

Comment: Makes perfect sense since `perldoc` states that an `END` block is executed outside the implicit loop. I count myself educated. Thanks.

Comment: @bu5hman lol don't count on anything you learn about perl from me, I'm very much a beginner

Comment: Makes me a 'preginner' then. Anyway the `}{` to `END` issue is at least documented here now. Couldn't find it anywhere else. Enough chat! Beer time for me now........ciao

Answer (score 0):

@rush use of `sed` didn't work in my shell so I went this way

```
grep -Poh '(?<=login":")[^"]*' json* | sort | uniq -c | awk  -v OFS=': ' 'BEGIN{print "{"}{print $2, $1}END{print"}"}' | sed -E 's/([0-9])$/\1,/g;s/:/\":/g;s/^([^{}])/\"\1/g'
```

The multiple `sed` can be amended if your shell lets you escape the `"` and print them in the `awk` statement.

```
grep -Poh '(?<=login":")[^"]*' json* | sort | uniq -c | awk  -v OFS=': ' 'BEGIN{print "{"}{print \"$2\", $1}END{print"}"}' | sed -E 's/([0-9])$/\1,/g'
```

In my shell `awk` choked on the `\"` in the second script. Not sure why but am sure that someone out there will tell me.

I also tried `jq` but it choked on the json files. There appears to be a syntax error

```
"this":"is' #is written so I edited these to
"this":"is"
```

Also `jq` didn't like the construct

```
{"a":"strange"} # so I also edited these to
b: {"a":"strange"}
```

If original files are supposed to be as per the edits made then `jq` works

```
jq '.login' json* | sort | uniq -c | awk -v OFS=': ' 'BEGIN{print "{"}{print $2, $1}END{print"}"}' | sed -E 's/([0-9])$/\1,/g'
```